# Culture ID 31770 (0x7C1A) is a neutral culture; a region cannot be created from it. Parameter name: culture

Tags: c#, webforms

I am using .net framework 2.0.
I have move website from **Windows server 2008 R2 Standard** to **Windows server 2019 Standard**
then after throw below error in my function.

[image]

[image]

My function code below

```
   protected string GetCultureFlagMapJS()
   {
        Dictionary<string, string> cultureCountryFlagMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        List<CountryFlags> flags = Flags();
        List<CultureInfo> codes = Codes();
        foreach (CultureInfo cultInfo in codes)
        {
            RegionInfo regInfo = new RegionInfo(cultInfo.LCID);
            CountryFlags flagMatch = flags.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Text == regInfo.EnglishName);
            if (flagMatch != null)
            {
                cultureCountryFlagMap.Add(cultInfo.Name, flagMatch.Value);
            }
        }
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsCultureCountryFlagMap = serializer.Serialize(cultureCountryFlagMap);
        return "var jsCultureCountryFlagMap = " + jsCultureCountryFlagMap + ";";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution, when i change my own method code and it's working fine.

MY changed method code here :

```
protected string GetCultureFlagMapJS()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> cultureCountryFlagMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    List<CountryFlags> flags = Flags();
    List<CultureInfo> codes = Codes();
    foreach (CultureInfo cultInfo in codes)
    {
        var ci = cultInfo;  // local copy, use ci from now on
        if (!ci.IsNeutralCulture)
        {                
            RegionInfo regInfo = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
            CountryFlags flagMatch = flags.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Text == regInfo.EnglishName);
            if (flagMatch != null)
            {
                cultureCountryFlagMap.Add(cultInfo.Name, flagMatch.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```